# generating log timestamps using Stored procedures in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, stored-procedures, logging, timestamp

I have a Stored Procedure, Which has some select Statements and insert statements.

Is there any way , I can log the Timestamps of execution before and after the sqls inside the Stored procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is not something you want to leave in permanently (i.e. it's just for debugging/performance analysis purposes) then your best bet is to use SQL Profiler and monitor the SP:StmtCompleted event which will record the stats for each statement within a sproc. You can dump this data to a db table.

**Edit: Running SQL Profiler:**
1) In SSMS, under Tools, select SQL Server Profiler
2) Connect to your db server you want to monitor
3) In the trace properties dialog that appears, go to the Events Selection tab and tick the "Show all events" checkbox
4) The grid will then show all types of events you can monitor. Find the Stored Procedures section, and in there cick the SP:StmtCompleted checkbox to define that you want to monitor that type of event.
5) The general tab allows you to save the trace to a file, or to a db table if you want to. Or, you don't have to save it to either, just display it to screen. You can always save it to a table/file later if you really need to. 
6) When you're ready just click "Run"
For a lot more info on SQL Profiler, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(SQL.90).aspx)

If this is something you want to keep (i.e. an audit table), then you'll need to INSERT records into your own audit table yourself e.g.

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
SET @StartTime = GETDATE()

SELECT Something FROM SomeTable WHERE....

INSERT MyAuditTable (Statement, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES ('SELECT Something FROM SomeTable WHERE...', @StartTime, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Ada,  

Yes, I just want to do for "debugging/performance analysis" purpose only.
i am new to Sql server, could you please provide the link or steps how to do "SQL Profiler and monitor the SP:StmtCompleted".

Thanks,

Comment: Open up Profiler from the SQL Server 2005 Performance program group. Create a new trace. On the "General" tab specify "Use this template" "TSQL_SPs". This will automatically preselect all interesting events. On the "Events" tab uncheck "Audit login" & "Audit Logout", because you don't need them for this. If you think, you have captured enough events, stop the trace and from the File menu you can decide what to do with the trace, e.g. where to store it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Add TSQL to write to an audit table at the start and end of execution, adding `TRY/CATCH` error handling to make sure an early exit doesn't occur.